# How to pass callback method from xaml? (Xamarin.form & WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

I'm making my custom image button on Xamarin form. 
But below my code is not working.

runtime error message :

```
Position 26:34. Cannot assign property "buttonCallback": type mismatch between "System.String" and "XXX.CircleImageButton+ClickedDelegate"
```

What's the right way to pass callback method from xaml?
And How do you call that technique?

Thanks.

myxaml.xaml

```
<local:CircleImageButton buttonCallback="buttonCallback"...
```

myxaml.xaml.cs

```
void buttonCallback()
{
...
}
```

CircleImageButton.cs

```
using System;
using ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XXX
{
    public class CircleImageButton : CircleImage
    {
        public delegate void ClickedDelegate();
        public ClickedDelegate buttonCallback { set; get; }

        public CircleImageButton ()
        {
            this.GestureRecognizers.Add (new TapGestureRecognizer{
                Command = new Command(() => {
                    this.Opacity = 0.6;
                    this.FadeTo(1);
                    this.buttonCallback();
                })
            });     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change your code to:

```
public event ClickedDelegate buttonCallback;
```

---

### Suggestion

For custom events, I'd use this structure:

**MyBarElement**

*Decalaration*

```
public event EventHandler FooHappend;
```

*Invocation*

```
FooHappend?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

**Page**

Then you can use

```
<MyBarElement FooHappend="OnFooHappend"></MyBarElement>
```

In your code behind

```
private void OnFooHappend(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Sven. Again.

Comment: Both works great. and I re-code as you suggessted. and It works great and better.

Comment: Thanks Sven. it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A brief addition to Sven's answer (as I am not yet allowed to comment); if you wish to use custom EventArgs in order to pass back customizable information, you must use:

```
public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> FooHappend;
```

along with:

```
FooHappend?.Invoke(this, new CustomEventArgs(MyValue.ToString()));
```

and:

```
private void OnFooHappend(object sender, CustomEventArgs eventArgs)
{  

}
```

which you can easily define like so:

```
public class CustomEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    private readonly string customString;

    public CustomEventArgs(string customString)
    {
        this.customString= customString;
    }

    public string CustomString
    {
        get { return this.customString; }
    }
}
```

Hope this saves someone an hour or two down the road :)